# ActivityNotFoundException - Android application using fb login and google maps

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-activity, facebook

I get the

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {mark.the.map/mark.the.map.ShowTheMap}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

error and I'm sure I have declared my activity in the AndroidManifest.xml - here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

      ...

        <activity android:name=".MarkTheMap" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        ...

</manifest>
```

I have the following app classes :

MarkTheMapActivity (Main) activity
FacebookConnect.java
ShowTheMap.java

I have tried cleaning the project, rebiuld, restart the Eclipse - nothing happens - the same error shows up. What do you suggest could be the reason for this mistake?

Comment: did u add your activity in menifest?

Comment: I do not see the activity ShowTheMap declared in your manifest?

Comment: Where is ShowTheMap in your manifest?

Comment: I fixed that - I was a typo- but now I get :
`07-27 13:24:47.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mark.the.map/mark.the.map.ShowTheMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ShowTheMap" 
</activity>
```

Comment: I putted it bot now a new error shows up: 

`07-27 13:24:47.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(729): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mark.the.map/mark.the.map.ShowTheMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Well, that's a separate issue. There's a bug in your ShowTheMap code. You'll need to open a new question including `ShowTheMap.java`, `mapView.xml`, and the full stack trace of your error.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared `ShowTheMap` Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`